# Algorithm/Method to save costs of running filtering proxy on AWS EC2

Tags: proxy, amazon-ec2, squid

I am trying to set up a Squid Proxy combined with DansGuardian Content filtering engine on EC2. I will be filtering traffic from mobile(IOS/Android) clients via this filtered proxy but that could mean a lot of traffic flowing through my system, since I will have to route all of the traffic through the DNS, which inturn could mean a lot Amazon EC2 costs!. Is there a known method/standard in which I can direct only known blacklisted traffic via this proxy in a cost effective manner?. Things I have explored include creating blacklists on the device and filtering right there , but that might mean I have to keep going back and changing (adding or removing sites) and this is not really feasible anyway.